# How to relate two matrices in C++?

Tags: c++

Imagine I have two matrices `name[]` that takes the names of n students as inputs and another matrix `marks[][]` that inputs the marks in 6 subjects of the student. Now, I have related the i-th index of the student `name[]` and the `marks[][]` in such a way that `marks[i][2]` is the marks of the student corresponding to `name[i]` in the name matrix.

> Now, I have to print the name of the student who has got the highest marks.

To calculate highest,I have used the following code-

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

    for ( j = 1; j < 6; j++)
    {
        total =total+marks[i][j];
    }

    if (total>hst)
        hst=total;
    total=0;
    cout<<hst<<"\n";
}
```

So,I have successfully found out the highest marks among all the students.
 But how do I relate the total marks with the name of the student in another matrix?

Comment: Just remember the value of your index `i` that corresponds to the highest marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to track index of student with the highest mark. In the code below I called it "topstudent"

```
int topstudent = 0;
int hst = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for ( j = 1; j < 6; j++)
    {
        total =total+marks[i][j];
    }
    if (total>hst) {
        hst=total;
        topstudent = i;
    }
    total=0;
    cout<<hst<<"\n";
    cout<<names[i]<<"\n"; 
}

cout<<"Final results: \n"; 
cout<<hst<<"\n"; 
cout<<names[topstudent]<<"\n"; 

cout<<"Final results: \n"; 
cout<<hst<<"\n"; 
cout<<names[topstudent]<<"\n";
```

Comment: Lovely...thanks for the answer... is there something we can do if I have 2 students and both get same total marks/

Comment: sure!  try to find out yourself first :)